# Почему символ табуляции в сниппетах эквивалентен 8 пробелам и остаётся таким же, а не трансформируется в 4 пробела?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, сниппеты

Если сделать просто блок кода (4 пробела и всё), то символ табуляции трансформируется в 4 пробела:

```
Это текст с символом табуляции (    ), которая трансформируется в 4 пробела.
```

А в сниппете эквивалентен 8 пробелам и остаётся таким же.
К сожалению, не могу привести пример (так как здесь нету сниппетов), но можете убедиться сами, что символ табуляции добавляется именно так.

Comment: а у меня почему-то ни во что не трансформируется: если вставлять таб, он так символом таба и остается, если нажимать на клавишу таб, то в сниппете вообще эквивалентно _двум_ пробелам.

Comment: @Grundy Переформулировал вопрос, спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: Все равно непонятно что надо сделать, чтобы воспроизвести.

Comment: Да [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614030/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83) к примеру. Внутри тега `head`.

Comment: [initial value: 8](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size) в стилях к сниппету он никак не выставляется поэтому используется значение 8 по умолчанию

Comment: Хорошо, но в блоке кода он трансформируется в 4 пробела, а в сниппете — нет. Вам не кажется это недоработкой?